# function to print text inverted (by a for loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I want to make a function that returns the text inverted.
The problem here is, 'x' doesn´t store the inverted text I don´t know why.

THIS IS THE CODE

```
def text_inverted(w):

    for i in range(len(w)-1,-1,-1):
        x=""
        x+=w[i]
    return x

print(text_inverted("hello"))
```

Comment: Because you set `x=""` in each loop iteration

Comment: Have a look at the ``reversed`` builtin as well.

Answer (score 2):

Move `x` outside of the for loop, because currently you are resetting x each time the for loops iterates:

```
def text_inverted(w):
    x = "" 

    for i in range(len(w)-1,-1,-1):
        x+=w[i]
    return x

print(text_inverted("hello")) #prints olleh
```

Another way of solving this is using Python's slicing notion:

```
def text_inverted(w):
    return w[::-1]

print(text_inverted("hello"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you reassign `x` to be the empty string in each iteration of the `for` loop. Move the statement `x = ''` above the loop and your function should work fine.

Demo:

```
>>> def text_inverted(w):
...     x = ''
...     for i in range(len(w)-1,-1,-1):
...         x += w[i]
...     return x
... 
>>> 
>>> print(text_inverted("hello"))
olleh
```

By the way, the idiomatic way to reverse a string uses slice notation.

```
>>> 'hello'[::-1]
'olleh'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is easier way.

```
a="hello"
print(a[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are resetting the value of `x` altogether in every iteration of the loop.

```
def inverted(w):
    i = 0;
    x = '';
    length = len(w);
    while i < length:
         x += w[length - 1];
         length = length - 1;
    return x;
print(inverted('hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you're not suppose to set the variable `x` inside the for-loop; just initialize outside of it.

A better and simple alternative is use the Python build-in solution:

```
w[::-1]
```

It will return the inverted `w` string.